# How to configure system to use the FIWARE yum repository?

Tags: yum, fiware, filab

I know that FI-WARE offers a public yum repository at http://repositories.testbed.fiware.org/ that can be used to install FI-WARE packages such as Orion contexto Broker.

However, how can I configure my system to use that repository? E.g. which .conf file I need to add in my /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory to make it work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a file fiware.repo in /etc/yum.repos.d/ with the following lines:

```
[fiware]
name=Fiware Repository
baseurl=http://repositories.lab.fiware.org/repo/rpm/$releasever
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

I hope it helps you.

**EDIT:** originally, baseurl were `http://repositories.lab.fiware.org/repo/rpm/x86_64/`. That is still working, but the correct one since April 2016 uses `$releasever`. In addition, `/x86_64` has been removed.

**EDIT:** originally, the name was `repositories.testbed.fiware.org` but it changed to `repositories.lab.fiware.org` on Feburary 2016.

Comment: Note that this answer is for FIWARE repositories in general. It may happen that a particular component doesn't have packages for a given release of CentOS (e.g. contextBroker at CentOS 7, by the time being).

Comment: This repository no longer supported by the link described above. The guide for use of the new yum repository is available here https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.0/admin/yum/index.html