# Running orion context broker

Tags: fiware-orion, filab

Following the tutorial about installing Orion, I installed contextBroker-0.5.0-1.x86_64.rpm and contextBroker-tests-0.5.0-1.x86_64.rpm.
After all, I decided to run Orion, but when I do using # contextBroker I get this notification
"contextBroker: error while loading shared libraries: libmicrohttpd.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I've read on the Internet that "libmicrohttpd.so.10" belongs to contextBroker-0.5.0-1.x86_64.rpm, so I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Version 0.5.0 is *very* old. I would recommend you to install the newest one that, at time of this writting, is 0.14.0.

You can install it in the following way:

1. Remove the old version (`rpm -e contextBroker`)
2. Configure FI-WARE yum respository (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331330/how-to-configure-system-to-use-the-fi-ware-yum-repository))
3. Install contextBroker running: `yum install contextBroker`
4. Ensure you have the newest version: `contextBroker --version`