# Where to find accumulator-server.py and contextBroker-test package?

Tags: fiware-orion

I am testing the Orion Context Broker, using orion-psb-R3.4.

I’ve read http://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Optional_packages

Where can we find the contextBroker-test package?
I want to use the accumulator-server.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accumulator-server.py is part of the contextBroker-tests package, that you can install doing the following:

1. Add FIWARE yum repository to your system (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331330/how-to-configure-system-to-use-the-fi-ware-yum-repository/24510985#24510985))
2. Install using the following command:

   ```
   yum install contextBroker-tests
   ```

Once installed, the accumualtor-server.py is exactlty in the following path:

```
/usr/share/contextBroker/tests/accumulator-server.py
```

It is recommented to create a symlink from /usr/local/bin to that file to have it at hand.

Comment: It is probably a good idea to match the contextBroker-tests package with the same version as the contextBroker (contextBroker --version). In my case I have used: yum install contextBroker-tests-0.14.0*   Creating the symlink is explained on [the wiki](http://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Unit_Testing_Plan)