# Cygnus error: class not found DestinationExtractor$Builder

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I'm trying to run Cygnus but there might be an error in cygnus.conf file or the way the connector is executed because nothing appears neither in my HDFS space in Cosmos nor in my MySQL. I've made a suscription and this works well. Here is my .conf file 
[1](http://topdigitalsensors.hol.es/cygnus.conf.txt) and what I get when executing cygnus [2](http://topdigitalsensors.hol.es/execution_flume.txt).

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Cygnus 0.5 (the one you are ussing according to the logs you are citing): the path to the matching table and the matching table file itself (cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.de.matching_table) have to exist.

- Upgrade to Cygnus 0.5.1 (typically `yum install cygnus`) if you have [the FIWARE yum repository rightly configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331330/how-to-configure-system-to-use-the-fi-ware-yum-repository/24510985#24510985).
- Keep using Cygnus 0.5, ensuring that the the path to the matching table and the matching table file itself exists.

Comment: I'm getting the same error after updating Cygnus, even setting at cygnus.conf the line _cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.de.matching_table_ to _/usr/cygnus/conf/matching_table.conf_.
The package I've installed is cygnus-0.5.1-10.gc797a60.x86_64.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the new log and new config file you are using with 0.5.1, please?