# How to test Fiware Cygnus

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I installed Fiware Cygnus on my Ubuntu 14.04 using this link [1]
and I am following this tutorial [2] to test it.

But when I get to the step of sending a notification such as:

```
$ ./notification.sh http://localhost:5050/notify
```

I get "connection refused" error.

Note: while starting cygnus I got the error bellow: I dont know what have I missed.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.DestinationExtractor$Builder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.flume.interceptor.InterceptorBuilderFactory.newInstance(InterceptorBuilderFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.configureInterceptors(ChannelProcessor.java:109)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.configure(ChannelProcessor.java:80)
    at org.apache.flume.conf.Configurables.configure(Configurables.java:41)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:353)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/07/15 16:35:07 ERROR node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Source http-source has been removed due to an error during configuration
org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Interceptor.Builder not found.
    at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.configureInterceptors(ChannelProcessor.java:114)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.configure(ChannelProcessor.java:80)
    at org.apache.flume.conf.Configurables.configure(Configurables.java:41)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:353)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.DestinationExtractor$Builder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.flume.interceptor.InterceptorBuilderFactory.newInstance(InterceptorBuilderFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.configureInterceptors(ChannelProcessor.java:109)
    ... 12 more
```

[1] https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus#section4.2

[2] https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/quick_start_guide.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Cygnus version you try to use is 0.8.2, then your problem might be the same I had, see [Cygnus startup error: ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320841/cygnus-startup-error-classnotfoundexception)