# fiware cygnus - unable to load synk for test

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I am trying to follow the quick start guide for Fiware Cygnus described [here](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-ngsi/quick_start_guide/index.html).

Actually, when I try to start Cygnus from command line, this is the error I get:

> time=2018-06-06T14:40:54.315UTC | lvl=ERROR | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=run | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable[142] : Failed to load configuration data. Exception follows.
>
> org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Unable to load sink type: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSITestSink, class: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSITestSink

I found similar questions on this topic, but not with this specific problem.
Thank you for your support!

Comment: This can be similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320841/cygnus-startup-error-classnotfoundexception,
but actually in my case the class not found is: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSITestSink

Comment: Hi Rafaele, Please can you add the command that you use for start Cygnus, also the agent config file content and any other information that help us to understand your problem.