# Installing the contextBroker

Tags: yum, fiware-orion

I got some problems installing the contextBroker on my own server.
I got a CentOS installation. Im trying to install the contextBroker with yum.
I have setup the repo as discribed in (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24510985/4953537)

Output when trying to install:

```
yum install contextBroker
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.plusline.de
 * epel: mirror.proserve.nl
 * extras: mirror.softaculous.com
 * updates: mirror.netcologne.de
No package contextBroker available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Output of yum repolist

```
yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.plusline.de
 * epel: mirror.proserve.nl
 * extras: mirror.softaculous.com
 * updates: mirror.netcologne.de
repo id                      repo name                                                 status
base                         CentOS-6 - Base                                           4926
epel                         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - i386              9467
extras                       CentOS-6 - Extras                                           34
mongodb                      MongoDB Repository                                         269
testbed-fi-ware              Fiware Repository                                          108
updates                      CentOS-6 - Updates                                         864
repolist: 15668
```

What am i missing here?

Update:

```
cat /etc/yum.repos.d/testbed-fi-ware.repo
[testbed-fi-ware]
name=Fiware Repository
baseurl=http://repositories.testbed.fi-ware.org/repo/rpm/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

"rpm -qa | grep contextBroker" doesnt give any output

Update:

I tryed to install the package manually and i installed all the dependancies listed on https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Installing

```
The contextBroker package (mandatory) depends on the following packages: boost-filesystem, boost-thread, libmicrohttpd (new requirement in 0.8.0), logrotate (new requirement in 0.13.0), libcurl (new requirement in 0.14.1) and boost-regex (new requirement in 0.22.0).
```

Still, when installing the RPM package( sudo rpm -i http://repositories.testbed.fiware.org/repo/rpm/x86_64/contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64.rpm) i get:

```
 Failed dependencies:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libboost_regex-mt.so.5()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libboost_system-mt.so.5()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libboost_thread-mt.so.5()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libcurl.so.4()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0)(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libm.so.6()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libmicrohttpd.so.10()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libpthread.so.0()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        librt.so.1()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.10)(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11)(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
        libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
```

Why do i get this?

Comment: i know it is a while but let me know which version of Cent OS are you using ? 7.x ?  Because this is not supported by Fiware. Use Cent Os 6.8 final this works very well

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes yum doesn't detect new packages in the repositories. In that case, I have found that the following command use to help:

```
yum clean all
```

next, try again

```
yum install contextBroker
```

Comment: I tryed above serveral times but no luck.Anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: In order to know other possible causes, please edit your question post to include the following: 1) the content of testbed-fi-ware.repo file (i.e. `cat /etc/yum.repos.d/testbed-fi-ware.repo`, 2) the output of the following command: `rpm -qa | grep contextBroker`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is installing directly from the repository with `rpm` command, e.g.:

```
sudo rpm -i http://repositories.testbed.fiware.org/repo/rpm/x86_64/contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

However, in this case, if some package dependency fails, you would need to deal with it manually.

**EDIT**: in the case of dependencies problems, you can use the following in order to know which package provides each dependency:

```
yum whatprovides libboost_filesystem-mt.*
yum whatprovides libstdc++.so.6
```

However, not sure if this would work in you case, given that the fail in `yum install contextBroker` at the very beginning makes me think if yum is not working fine in your environment...

Comment: I updated my question with manually installing the RPM package

Comment: Answer has been edited to include more info about dealing with missing dependencies.

Comment: Indeed this also doesn't work.... when i do the whatprovices function, it gives me a package, when i try to install it, it says its allready installed....why is it in the failed dependancy list?

Comment: It seems that something is definitively broken in your yum system... I would recommend you to review yum documentation and get support from yum experts.