# Fiware orion context broker - lack of libraries

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Hello I was installing Orion Context Broker. I've downloaded them from:
https://forge.fiware.org/frs/download.php/1641/contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64.rpm

and tryied to install:
rpm -i contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64.rpm

And I got this output on Centos 6.6:

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# rpm -i contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    boost-thread is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
    libboost_regex-mt.so.5()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
    libboost_thread-mt.so.5()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
    libmicrohttpd is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
    libmicrohttpd.so.10()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64
```

Your instalation instruction isnt telling anything about installing additional libraries :)

https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide

Do You know how can i fix it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the installation manual specifies the dependencies in [this section](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Requirements):

> The contextBroker package (mandatory) depends on the following
>   packages: boost-filesystem, boost-thread, libmicrohttpd (new
>   requirement in 0.8.0), logrotate (new requirement in 0.13.0), libcurl
>   (new requirement in 0.14.1) and boost-regex (new requirement in
>   0.22.0).

Anyway, the recommended way of installing Orion in CentOS 6.x is using yum, which automatically deals with dependencies. First, add the [FIWARE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331330/how-to-configure-system-to-use-the-fi-ware-yum-repository) and [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repositories. Next, run (as root user):

```
yum install contextBroker
```