# Fiware IDAS & Orion Production Deployment

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I would like to know what is the common deployment pattern for IDAS and Orion in a production environment.  Are they usually deployed as docker images or as a native service?  If they are as a docker images then do they usually go together in one container or separate containers?

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply.  But I think I wasn't clear with my question.  I know that you can deploy Fiware IDAS and Orion as docker images or as native services (RPM). But has anyone out there really deployed them in a production environment i.e. outside the lab? If so then how did you deploy them, docker or native (RPM)?

Comment: If you use docker then did you have the mqtt broker and idas on the same container and orion on another? Is it a good idea to have the IDAS on one host and Orion on another, or are they always installed on the same host, (docker or not)?

Comment: The most of production deployments for Orion that I know uses RPM. However, that doesn't preclude the usage de docker also as a valid way of working.

Answer (score 1):

I can provide an answer from the point of view of Orion Context Broker (I hope that some of my colleagues from IDAS team can answer also that part).

Deployment options (look for slides "How to get Orion" in [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/fermingalan/fiware-managing-context-information-at-large-scale)) are the following ones:

- Image in FIWARE Lab cloud
- Docker contaniner
- VirtualBox image
- RPM installation (from [FIWARE repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331330/how-to-configure-system-to-use-the-fiware-yum-repository))
- Compiling from sources

Answer (score 1):

For IDAS it depends on the specific IoT-Agent you are using.
If you are using Ultralight2.0/HTTP or MQTT to connect devices, all the information for installation is available here:

https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-IoTAgent-Cplusplus/blob/release/1.3.0/README.md

On the other hand, if you will use OMA LWM2M/CoAP to connect devcies, this info is here:

https://github.com/telefonicaid/lightweightm2m-iotagent/blob/master/docs/administrationGuide.md

Also, docker files are available here:
http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/backend-device-management-idas/creating-instances

Hope this helps.
Cheers,