# Installing FIWARE orion with non-existing dependencies

Tags: yum, fiware, fiware-orion

I'm trying to install Orion in my webserver. I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/develop/doc/manuals/admin/install.md) but I get this error when I try to install it:

```
# yum install contextBroker
Error: Paquete: contextBroker-0.27.0-1.x86_64 (fiware)
         Necesita: libboost_thread-mt.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Paquete: contextBroker-0.27.0-1.x86_64 (fiware)
         Necesita: libboost_regex-mt.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Paquete: contextBroker-0.27.0-1.x86_64 (fiware)
         Necesita: libboost_system-mt.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Paquete: contextBroker-0.27.0-1.x86_64 (fiware)
         Necesita: libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5()(64bit)
```

> VERSION:
> CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
> NAME="CentOS Linux"
> VERSION="7 (Core)"
> ID="centos"
> ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
> VERSION_ID="7"
> PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
> ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
> CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
> HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
> BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"
>
> CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
> CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
> REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
> REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
>
> 12.5.30 cos7.build1205150826.19
> CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
> CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

How can I resolve these dependencies? I tried adding the repo that I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331330/how-to-configure-system-to-use-the-fiware-yum-repository/24510985#24510985)

Comment: Could you edit your post to include information about the CentOS version in which you are performing the installation, please? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I mean the version of the distribution, typically the content of the `/etc/redhat-release` file. Could you add that information to the question post, please? Thanks!

Comment: I understand that you are using CentOS or RHEL... Is that correct?

Comment: check now please, thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Orion RPM doesn't work in CentOS 7.x. From [Requirements section](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/install/index.html#requirements) in the installation documentation:

> Operating system: CentOS/RedHat. The reference operating system is
>   CentOS 6.3 but it should work also in any later CentOS/RedHat 6.x
>   version.

Thus, my recomendation is to use a CentOS 6.x operating system.

Another alternative would be to install from sources, but [the procedure](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/build_source/index.html) is also oriented to CentOS 6.x and some adjustment would be probably needed for CentOS 7.x.

Comment: thanks for your reponse, bad news again with this enabler... I can't downgrade the server for security reasons, we will lose the SSL certificate...

Comment: As alternative, you could use docker-based deployment. As long as your system supports docker (and I think CentOS 7.1 should support) you can deploy Orion. Please have a look to https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/orion