# fiware could not be installed

Tags: rpm, fiware-orion

I am trying to install contextBroker following doc: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/develop/doc/manuals/admin/install.md#using-yum-(recommended)

the yum installation did not work, therefore I tried to download https://forge.fiware.org/frs/?group_id=7 to install

```
    rpm -i contextBroker-1.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

then it shows the error:error:

```
  contextBroker-tests-1.2.1-1.x86_64.rpm: not an rpm package (or package manifest):
```

Could any please tell me what happened?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded it, and it looks like their webserver is misconfigured. They are inserting HTML at the beginning of the RPM and corrupting it. You will need to use a utility to strip the text from the beginning. `dd` is likely easiest once you figure out how much junk to remove.

Original answer (useful to keep because it tells about `file` and `yum`):

> "not an rpm package" sounds like the download corrupted. Try running "`file`" on it and see what it tells you about it. I didn't see a hash on the download page, so you can't verify with that.
>
> `yum` is a nicer interface to `rpm` so you can try "`yum localinstall contextBroker-1.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm`".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downloading the RPM for Forge, the recommended way of installing Context Broker is the following (as described in [the documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/admin/install/index.html#installation)):

- Configure the FIWARE yum repository (as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331330/how-to-configure-system-to-use-the-fi-ware-yum-repository/24510985#24510985)).
- Do (as root): `yum install contextBroker`